# how to change the colorbox image size?

Tags: media, javascript

I have a content type named gallery and under this, I have created
the gallery content which is belong to that content type and added the
multiple images but the problem is when I click the thumbnail image
color box window opened but small images opened.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new image style of any size you want to open the image in colobox.
2. Now browse to manage display of your content type.
3. Select the formate 'Colorbox' for image field.
4. Add newly created image style for **Colorbox image style**, please follow below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: i did but it doesn't open the large plese check i added the image in question